# Is af_packet.ko supposed to automatically load?

Tags: linux, configuration, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I had an issue with trying to get the wpa_supplicant to run on board running a custom Embedded Linux distribution. After some debugging it turned out that it was because the domain type PF_PACKET was not supported by the kernel:

```
drv->eapol_tx_sock = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

This is supported by the af_packet module and loading it beforehand fixed the problem. I noticed that it also has the alias "pf-net-17" and it appears that the kernel can load this module at runtime if requested from user-space via the alias. I tested this in another Embedded Linux distribution and sure enough this seems to be the case. It was loaded after the supplicant was called.

Does anyone know why this functionality is not working in the first setup? Maybe I missed a kernel setting?

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 reasons why this worked on another system and not on your board:

- the PF_PACKET was configured to be built in the kernel or not as a module.
- The af_packet module was automatically loaded at runtime, either as a dependancy to another module or as a module to be automatically loaded at boot

I suggest that you read this [document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Loading_a_Module.html) about module loading which is quite concise, yet complete and precise.

A way to fix your problem would be to make sure that depmod was run for your target system so that the module dependancy for your build is updated of load the af_packet module automatically at boot.

Another place to look at is [udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev), which is meant to [load modules](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter07/udev.html) according to the devices detected by the kernel. Maybe this is also missing/misconfigured in your system.